WCF Problem when not matching function parameters
I made a test function with WCF and developed it by updating the reference in the client

Service- test(string a) ,  Client- test(string a)


The service then modified the parameter for this function and debugged it, but it worked fine

service - test(string  a, int b, int c)   ,  Client- test(string a) (Still no reference update)


So I did one more test, and the service made overloading with different parameters

service - test(string a, int b, int c)     ,  Client- test(string a) (Still no reference update)
service - test(string a, string b string c),

of couse In case 3, it didn't work.

Finally, I wonder why number 2 worked
I want to know how it works when there is one function and when there are two functions(Overloading).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading
